# 2 highschool limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

Compute
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}(1+\sqrt[n]{2}+\sqrt[n]{3}+\cdots+ \sqrt[n]{n}-n)$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{\ln x}}{{(\ln x)}^x}$$

Comment: For second, top is $e^{(log x)^2}$, bottom is $e^{x\log\log x}$. Bottom wins big time.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: thanks for your hint / way! The 2nd one seems rather troublesome and couldn't find anything nice/fast.

Comment: You mean the first one, $(1/n)(\sum\sqrt[k]{n}-n)$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas: No. I mean exactly what I wrote in my question.

Comment: One can find more than one solution to the first question, for example by approximating by integral. It is just that there is a lot of slack, so much cruder estimate will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculation with brute force:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{\ln x}}{{(\ln x)}^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{\ln^2 x}}{{e^{\ln(\ln x) x}}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\ln^2 x-x\ln(\ln x)}
$$
Then,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln^2 x-x\ln(\ln x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\ln^2 x}x-\ln(\ln x)}{\frac1x}=\frac{0-\infty}{0^+}=-\infty
$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{\ln x}}{{(\ln x)}^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\ln^2 x-x\ln(\ln x)}=0
$$

Comment: @Chris'ssister Well then there is a mitake somewhere.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah I noticed. Thanks